# I can't get color to fill navigation bar. There's white showing on the left side

Tags: navigation

I can't get the navigation bar to display fully across my screen with color. There is white space on the left side.

Here is a link to my site: dc2.e6b.myftpupload.com

Comment: Tiffany, we need more information, eh. What kind of a screen is it? (Desktop, cell/mobile, ...) What software are you using to make the bar? You will find that people here won't read a lot of code. Try to boil your problem down to a few lines of code that display the problem you're experiencing and display those in text. Accompany the textual stuff with an image showing the screen or portion of the screen that displays the problem. Be as explicit yet as brief and compact as possible. And best of luck! Oh, and add some tags that indicate which software is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

Your styles are being applied to you `<nav>`, which is centered within several `<div>` tags to control its centering.

You need to apply the styles (`background-color`, `border-top`, and `border-bottom`) to the outer containing element - in your case it would be the `<div>` with class of `.site-topbar` to get it to apply across the entire width of the screen.